# 'Find' Instruction clarification

Tags: find

I have the following instructions:

1. Find all files in the directory `/x/y/z` with the extension `.jpg`.
2. Write a list of matching **filenames**, one per line, to the file `/x/y/file1.txt`.
3. Ensure that you specify the absolute path to each file.

Can you assist with understanding this instruction? I initially thought of using the following command:

```
find /x/y/z -name '*.jpg' -exec basename '{}' >> /x/y/file1.txt \;
```

However, given the last instruction (...absolute path), I consider:

```
find /x/y/z -name '*.jpg' -exec pathname '{}' >> /x/y/file1.txt \;
```

Which is the correct response (command) to the question/instruction?

Comment: It seems that requirements #2 and #3 are either in opposition, or the word `filenames` should be taken to mean `pathnames`. In this case `ls /x/y/z/*.jpg >/x/y/file1.txt` would suffice, but it's not clear to me how to satisfy both #2 and #3 if `filenames` is taken as its usual meaning of a filename component without path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I'm assuming that the second point of your instructions actually means "pathnames" rather than "filenames".  The third point does not make sense otherwise.

The `find` utility will, by default, output the full path to the found files, relative to the top-level search path.

In the command

```bsh
find /x/y/z -name '*.jpg' -print
```

... `find` will print out pathnames like `/x/y/z/foo/bar/baz.jpg`.  If the top-level search path is the absolute pathname to some directory, then the output would automatically be absolute pathnames to found files.

On the other hand, if you're using

```bsh
find x/y/z -name '*.jpg' -print
```

(note the lack of `/` at the start of `x/y/z`), then you will obviously get relative pathnames outputted.

You may turn these into absolute pathnames using the utility `realpath` on Linux:

```bsh
find x/y/z -name '*.jpg' -exec realpath {} +
```

This calls `realpath` with batches of found pathnames.

On non-Linux systems, the same `realpath` utility may be installed if one installs GNU coreutils (but it may then be called `grealpath`).

See also `man realpath` (or `man grealpath`).

---

Re-reading your instructions, there is nothing in them that implies that you should be using `find`.  You don't need to use `find` if you're only concerned with the names in a single directory.

The exercise could just as well be solved by

```bsh
printf '%s\n' /x/y/z/*.jpg >/x/y/file1.txt
```

This lists all names ending with `.jpg` in the directory `/x/y/z`.  If you don't have the absolute path to that directory at hand, then use

```bsh
realpath x/y/z/*.jpg >/x/y/file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda and roamima. This is very helpful. I will work with these insights.